# jQuery click event without double dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm new to jQuery. I want to make a simple drop down menu with click event. Here is the html structure:

```
<ul id="menubar">
        <li class="menu">
            <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul class="submenubar">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu">
            <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul class="submenubar">
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>​
```

I made the script as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('li.submenu').hide()
            $('li.menu').click(function(e){
                $(this).find('li.submenu', this).slideToggle('fast'); 
                e.stopPropagation();
            })
        })​
```

But the drop down is overlapping. That's not what I want. All I want is:
 - If I click Menu 1, it will show the Submenu 1. The other Menus and Submenus are hidden.
 - Then if I click Menu 2, the Submenu 2 will be shown as the Submenu 1 will be hidden.
 - And so on...

What should I do? Can anybody help me to solve this? Thanks for your response..

Comment: How does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/M6jdT/

Answer (score 0):

hey check this out click on menu1 it will show submenu1 hides other again whn u click menu1 then it will menu2 wil b show try this

http://jsfiddle.net/96xnB/